# can i meter or set a size limit to an s3 folder

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'd like to set up a separate s3 bucket folder for each of my mobile app users for them to store their files.  However, I also want to set up size limits so that they don't use up too much storage.  Additionally, if they do go over the limit I'd like to offer them increased space if they sign up for a premium service.

Is there a way I can set folder file size limits through s3 configuration or api?  If not would I have to use the apis somehow to calculate folder size on every upload?  I know that there is the devpay feature in Amazon but it might be a hassle for users to sign up with Amazon if they want to just use small amount of free space.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way to do this, probably at least in part because there is actually no such thing as "folders" in S3.  There is only the *appearance* of folders.

> Amazon S3 does not have concept of a folder, there are only buckets and objects. The Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept using the object key name prefixes.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html</sup>

All of the keys in an S3 bucket are actually in a flat namespace, with the `/` delimiter used as desired to conceptually divide objects into logical groupings that look like folders, but it's only a convenient illusion.  It seems impossible that S3 would have a concept of the size of a folder, when it has no actual concept of "folders" at all.

If you don't maintain an authoritative database of what's been stored by clients (which suggests that all uploads should pass through an app server rather than going directly to S3, which is the the only approach that makes sense to me *at all*) then your only alternative is to poll S3 to discover what's there.  An imperfect shortcut would be for your application to read the S3 bucket logs to discover what had been uploaded, but that is only provided on a best-effort basis.  It should be reliable but is not guaranteed to be perfect.

> This service provides a best effort attempt to log all access of objects within a bucket. Please note that it is possible that the actual usage report at the end of a month will slightly vary.
>
> Your other option is to develop your own service that sits between users and Amazon S3, that monitors all requests to your buckets/objects.
>
> <sup>— http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1109#13</sup>

Again, having your app server mediate all requests seems to be the logical approach, and would also allow you to detect immediately (as opposed to "discover later") that a user had exceeded a threshold.

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain a seperate database in the cloud to hold each users total hdd usage count. Its easy to manage the count via S3 Object Lifecycle Events which could easily trigger a Lambda which in turn writes to a DB.