# How to check image file size through PHP before uploading to Amazon S3?

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3

I just had a question about checking image file size.  How do you do that in PHP(server-side), or even through javascript, before the image gets uploaded straight to S3?  In addition for personal reasons, I cannot use HTML5 to achieve that.

And I am aware of solutions such as first uploading to my own server to do the checking there, and then uploading to S3.  But this takes up loads of bandwith size, so it is out of the solution set.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would love to know the reason against HTML5 :)

Comment: Client-side tests would be pointless anyway since you can't trust the client.

Comment: True. I was just curious. As for the question: There should be a method in the S3 API I'm sure...

Comment: Hi everyone, thank you for responding speedily. @Pointy, if client-side tests are pointless, why do a lot of people recommend HTML5 file api, or does that somehow work on the server-side?

Comment: @Dominik, thanks for your recommendation. I'll investigate.

Comment: Client-side tests are definitely not "pointless".  It is important to keep in mind that malicious users can manipulate any client-side code fairly easily, but that doesn't make such checks a waste of time.

Comment: hi, i think this is the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check the file size before the file is sent to S3, and you are sending it directly to S3 without sending it to a server you control first, your only option is to check the `size` property of each `File` or `Blob` you are going to send to your S3 bucket.  This is possible in all browsers that support the File API, which is pretty much all browsers other than IE9 and older.  For older browsers, you cannot test sizes client-side.

I'm not sure why you mentioned PHP in your question, and, at the same time, said you do not want to send the files to a server you control first.  If you want to check the size of a file before sending it to S3 via some PHP, then of course you will have to send the file to your server first, as PHP is a server side language.  If you do indeed not want to send files to your server, you can of course send the files directly to S3 via the browser, and check the size first if the browser supports the File API.  This is generally what happens in [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com), a library I maintain that supports direct uploads to S3 from the browser without sending the files to a server you control first.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  You're right, I did have a contradiction in my question.  Sorry for that.  I suppose I will have to make a decision between the two solutions I posed, or maybe even use your suggestion.  I also thank you for the expediency of your answer.

Comment: hi, and thanks!. but how to handle a user changing your js validation code and uploading more then the allowed size?

Comment: ok i think the solution is specifying it at the policy like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @dowi sorry this is late, but thanks for that!  It's really helpful.  Cheers!