# How to set content-length-range for s3 browser upload via boto

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, reactjs, boto, boto3

## The Issue

I'm trying to upload images directly to S3 from the browser and am getting stuck applying the content-length-range permission via boto's S3Connection.generate_url method.

There's plenty of information about [signing POST forms](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434), [setting policies in general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type) and even a [heroku method for doing a similar submission](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python). What I can't figure out for the life of me is how to add the "content-length-range" to the signed url.

With boto's generate_url method (example below), I can specify policy headers and have got it working for normal uploads. What I can't seem to add is a policy restriction on max file size.

## Server Signing Code

```
## django request handler 
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
import mimetypes
import json

conn = S3Connection(settings.S3_ACCESS_KEY, settings.S3_SECRET_KEY)
object_name = request.GET['objectName']
content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(object_name)[0]

signed_url = conn.generate_url(
    expires_in = 300, 
    method = "PUT", 
    bucket = settings.BUCKET_NAME, 
    key = object_name,
    headers = {'Content-Type': content_type, 'x-amz-acl':'public-read'})

return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'signedUrl': signed_url}))
```

On the client, I'm using the [ReactS3Uploader](https://github.com/odysseyscience/react-s3-uploader) which is based on [tadruj's s3upload.js script](https://github.com/tadruj/s3upload-coffee-javascript). It shouldn't be affecting anything as it seems to just pass along whatever the signedUrls covers, but copied below for simplicity.

## ReactS3Uploader JS Code (simplified)

```
uploadFile: function() {
    new S3Upload({
        fileElement: this.getDOMNode(),
        signingUrl: /api/get_signing_url/,
        onProgress: this.props.onProgress,
        onFinishS3Put: this.props.onFinish,
        onError: this.props.onError
    });
},

render: function() {
    return this.transferPropsTo(
        React.DOM.input({type: 'file', onChange: this.uploadFile})
    );
}
```

## S3upload.js

```
S3Upload.prototype.signingUrl = '/sign-s3';
S3Upload.prototype.fileElement = null;

S3Upload.prototype.onFinishS3Put = function(signResult) {
    return console.log('base.onFinishS3Put()', signResult.publicUrl);
};

S3Upload.prototype.onProgress = function(percent, status) {
    return console.log('base.onProgress()', percent, status);
};

S3Upload.prototype.onError = function(status) {
    return console.log('base.onError()', status);
};

function S3Upload(options) {
    if (options == null) {
        options = {};
    }
    for (option in options) {
        if (options.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            this[option] = options[option];
        }
    }
    this.handleFileSelect(this.fileElement);
}

S3Upload.prototype.handleFileSelect = function(fileElement) {
    this.onProgress(0, 'Upload started.');
    var files = fileElement.files;
    var result = [];
    for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var f = files[i];
        result.push(this.uploadFile(f));
    }
    return result;
};

S3Upload.prototype.createCORSRequest = function(method, url) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (xhr.withCredentials != null) {
        xhr.open(method, url, true);
    }
    else if (typeof XDomainRequest !== "undefined") {
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    }
    else {
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
};

S3Upload.prototype.executeOnSignedUrl = function(file, callback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', this.signingUrl + '&objectName=' + file.name, true);
    xhr.overrideMimeType && xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var result;
            try {
                result = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            } catch (error) {
                this.onError('Invalid signing server response JSON: ' + xhr.responseText);
                return false;
            }
            return callback(result);
        } else if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status !== 200) {
            return this.onError('Could not contact request signing server. Status = ' + xhr.status);
        }
    }.bind(this);
    return xhr.send();
};

S3Upload.prototype.uploadToS3 = function(file, signResult) {
    var xhr = this.createCORSRequest('PUT', signResult.signedUrl);
    if (!xhr) {
        this.onError('CORS not supported');
    } else {
        xhr.onload = function() {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                this.onProgress(100, 'Upload completed.');
                return this.onFinishS3Put(signResult);
            } else {
                return this.onError('Upload error: ' + xhr.status);
            }
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.onerror = function() {
            return this.onError('XHR error.');
        }.bind(this);
        xhr.upload.onprogress = function(e) {
            var percentLoaded;
            if (e.lengthComputable) {
                percentLoaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                return this.onProgress(percentLoaded, percentLoaded === 100 ? 'Finalizing.' : 'Uploading.');
            }
        }.bind(this);
    }
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', file.type);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('x-amz-acl', 'public-read');
    return xhr.send(file);
};

S3Upload.prototype.uploadFile = function(file) {
    return this.executeOnSignedUrl(file, function(signResult) {
        return this.uploadToS3(file, signResult);
    }.bind(this));
};


module.exports = S3Upload;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated here as I've been banging my head against the wall for quite a few hours now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't add it to a signed `PUT` URL. This only works with the signed policy that goes along with a `POST` because the two mechanisms are very different.

Signing a URL is a lossy (for lack of a better term) process.  You generate the string to sign, then sign it. You send the signature with the request, but you discard and do not send the string to sign.  S3 then reconstructs what the string to sign should have been, for the request it receives, and generates the signature you should have sent with that request.  There's only one correct answer, and S3 doesn't know what string you actually signed.  The signature matches, or doesn't, either because you built the string to sign incorrectly, or your credentials don't match, and it doesn't know which of these possibilities is the case.  It only knows, based on the request you sent, the string you *should have signed* and what the signature *should have been*.

With that in mind, for `content-length-range` to work with a signed URL, the client would need to actually send such a header with the request... which doesn't make a lot of sense.

Conversely, with `POST` uploads, there is more information communicated to S3.  It's not only going on whether your signature is valid, it also has your policy document... so it's possible to include directives -- policies -- with the request.  They are protected from alteration by the signature, but they aren't encrypted or hashed -- the entire policy is readable by S3 (so, by contrast, we'll call this the opposite, "lossless.")

This difference is why you can't do what you are trying to do with `PUT` while you can with `POST`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot for taking the time to write that out clearly, really appreciated!

Comment: But, I wonder why S3 cannot simply enforce the standard "Content-Length" header for setting exact size?  I find I can set this to any value and the PUT still succeeds.

Comment: @user1055568 I don't understand what you're saying about S3 not enforcing the `Content-Length` header.  Can you clarify?

Comment: I am finding that I can set an arbitrary value, and S3 will still accept the file PUT.  However, it just occurred to me that the HTTP engine I am using (NSURLConnection on iOS) might be correcting my bogus values.  I am just exploring that now.  If that is what is happening, and S3 does reject Content-Length not matching file size, then can use V4 signing protocol to include the Content-Length in the signature.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening.  iOS is setting correct Content-Length regardless of what I specify.  So, signed Content-Length header might work to regulate upload size, assuming you know size in advance. However, I still can't be certain that S3 will reject mismatch with file size until I figure out how to send false Content-Length.

Comment: *"If that is what is happening, and S3 does reject Content-Length not matching file size, then can use V4 signing protocol to include the Content-Length in the signature"* True.  Also, S3 *should* reject invalid content-length if longer than the payload by eventually returning a timeout error (as it times out waiting for more data); an upload longer than the stated content length is more likely to simply be truncated.  If your motivation is data integrity, Setting `Content-MD5:` to the base64 md5 hash of the payload is guaranteed to work -- S3 *will* reject an upload that does not match.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens based on some experiments with CURL.  S3 truncates any data beyond Content-Length specified.  So, that works to enforce PUT size limits as long as clients can specify the exact size they wish to PUT when they acquire the pre-signed URL from the server, as is easy to do in my case.