# Restricting file types on amazon s3 bucket with a policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to set up so the only file types the bucket can hold would be png, jpeg, and gif images. I'm trying to put in a bucket policy like this

```
{
    "conditions": [
        {"bucket": "bucketname"},
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/jpeg"],
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/png"],
        ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/gif"],
        ["content-length-range", 0, 10485760]
    ]
}
```

Then I'm also trying to limit the size but when I try to update my policy I get the error "Invalid policy element - conditions"

I tried using the answer from here - [s3 direct upload restricting file size and type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type) so that's where I made my code from but I'm not sure the correct approach to do this since my policy isn't even being accepted by amazon.

Comment: Is that your entire policy document? Because that's not a complete document. Look at these example policy documents: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html

Comment: Upload the whole policy you will be using for this as above is incomplete code.

Comment: The caveat being that just because someone uploads a file named "blah.png" doesn't mean it's actually a PNG file, and S3 can't validate file formats.  If you really want to make sure you're only getting those formats, you'll have to confirm some other way.

Comment: are you setting up S3 bucket policy (which is detailed below) or trying to [setup post form s3 policy](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/1434) the answer you're pointing refers to the 2nd but looks like you talk about the 1st point

Comment: chaste the following [tutorial](https://medium.com/@anjanava.biswas/uploading-files-to-aws-s3-from-react-app-using-aws-amplify-b286dbad2dd7), it explains how to generate the user pool id and assign suitable policies to that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the policy generator for this if you're not sure how to write, for example you would have something like

```
{
  "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.jpg",
      "Principal": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968543787",
      "Action": [
        "s3:PutObject"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.png",
      "Principal": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

As said from [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Resource) you can specify multiple resources and aggregate this part, so no need to multiply the statement

```
    "Resource": [
      "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.jpg",
      "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.png",
      "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.gif",
    ],
```

so you get something like

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
        "Action": [
          "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.jpg",
          "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.png",
          "arn:aws:s3:::<yourbucket>/*.gif",
        ],
        "Principal": "*"
      }
    ]
}
```

you can access policy generator when you create your bucket policy

[image]

Comment: This only checks the file extension and not actual type of the file. A file with extension .jpg need not necessarily be an image file.

Comment: @bangde this has been highlighted in the comments above that if you want to validate the content type, you cant do it in the bucket policy, you can do that in a post form s3 policy

Comment: Careful. The example above doesn't check the **real mimetype** just the extension

Comment: Also it has no principle, it means anyone can access your bucket.

Answer (score 2):

I talked with AWS support engineer, the `conditions.starts-with` restriction is only supported by HTTP POST policy (eg: policy for browser form-field upload request). With this policy, it should be impossible to limit `mineType` when you or your users upload files with HTTP PUT request.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html#sigv4-PolicyConditions.

For common policy, you can see available `Condition` keys here, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazons3.html

**And I find there is another solution which can restrict mineType,**

1. specify mineType for your html element, like this: `<input type="file" accept="image/bmp,image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif"/>`
2. then you can get `bmp`, `jpeg`, `png` and `gif` through code, and you can set them as file URL extension of S3 object before upload.
3. Finally you can add general policy to limit file URL extension like below. Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-allow-certain-file-types/

```
{
    "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
          "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
              "AWS": "IAM-USER-ARN"
          },
          "Action": "s3:PutObject",
          "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.bmp",
              "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.jpeg",
              "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.png",
              "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*.gif"
         ]
     }
  ]
}
```

4. So that you restrict the mimeType from browser side

Comment: When you try this, it will show the following error `Invalid principal in policy`. As the sentence `"AWS": "IAM-USER-ARN"` is wrong