# s3 upload policy OR condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am doing s3 browser based uploads by following this guide - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html

My upload policy looks like this -

```
"conditions":[
            { "bucket": bucket },
            ["starts-with", "$key", key],
            {"success_action_status","201"},
            { "acl": acl },
            ["content-length-range", 1, filesize],
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/"]
        ]
```

Right now this policy allows all image format.

Now I want to allow only specific image format which are png,jpeg and gif only

I am looking for something like this -

```
["starts-with", "$Content-Type", "image/png or image/jpg or image/gif"]
```

I haven't been able to find anything specific. Is it even possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Restricting file types on amazon s3 bucket with a policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617844/restricting-file-types-on-amazon-s3-bucket-with-a-policy)