# Restricting file types on amazon s3 bucket to specific folder with a policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a bucket policy that allows the whole account access to upload objects, but limit a specific folder to a specific file ext, for example:

```
arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/prefixname/*.jpg
```

However, after following the below example, it seems this is either only possible at a bucket level, or it restricts uploading specifically to the resource specified.

Example:
[Restricting file types on amazon s3 bucket with a policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617844/restricting-file-types-on-amazon-s3-bucket-with-a-policy)

My bucket policy looks like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "Policy1464968545158",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/folder/*.csv"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1464968483619",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "NotResource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET/folder/*.csv"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Now with the above policy, it limits only uploads to that specific prefix.

I have tried using this in conjunction with a IAM policy, but the DENY statement pretty much over rides it.

I have also tried to leave out the deny statement and then use an IAM policy to grant access to the bucket and the resources, but my IAM user is still able to upload all extension types to all the different prefixes.

Has anyone been able to get this working at an account level, and not a user level?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but no IAM policy is going to check a file extension for you  of the object being uploaded and choose the right folder for it.

Comment: So I would like to allow the whole account access to PUT all file types to a bucket, however, I want to limit one prefix to only allow csv file to be written to it. I can do this at a bucket level, but struggling to do this at a prefix level. Also, is this even possible?

Comment: Can you please show an example how this works on the bucket level?

Comment: At a bucket level, you would just remove the /folder prefix. Then everyone in that account will only be able to upload specific extensions to that bucket.