# Upload the same name to Amazon S3 but keep the same permission

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Just my thinking. Some of us may work on several files and frequently upload the same file with the same name onto Amazon S3. By default, the permission will be reset. Assuming that I don't use Versioning.
And I have a need to keep the same permission for any uploaded file which has the same name file existed on current Amazon S3.

I know it may not a good idea but technically how we can realize it?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to an ACL on the object? You'll need to specify the same ACL when you store the object. It will completely replace the existing object, including all of its settings.

Comment: yes, it relates to object ACL. It's easy to manually adjust ACL of new objects. However, when the number of objects increases, it'll take much time.

Comment: How are you using ACLs to control security? Are you using them to make particular objects public, or to grant access to particular users? ACLs are not a common way to control security. What is your use-case for wanting to use them?

Comment: Not mandatory to use object ACL as we can instead use IAM policy to control object permission. A few simple use cases I thought about are: upload a bunch of files for static website, or certain guidelines which follow the name convention (so the same names)

Comment: The easiest way to make objects public is with a [Bucket Policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html), which can make a whole bucket, or a path within a bucket, public. You can also specify wildcards, see: [Restricting file types on amazon s3 bucket with a policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37618544/174777)

Answer (score 0):

It is **not possible** to upload an object and request that the existing ACL settings be kept on the new object.

Instead, you should specify the ACL when the object is uploaded.

Comment: Thanks John. I was thinking about a better way to automate updating Object ACL.


May we write a lambda function to modify the ACL for a new uploaded object to the specific bucket?

Comment: You can't simply modify the ACL. You will actually need to **copy the object to itself** while specifying a different ACL.