# S3 direct upload restrict file type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

I generate a presigned post like this : (Note: I am using aws-sdk v1)

```
 @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(
                            key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", 
                            success_action_status: '201',
                            acl: 'public-read',
                            content_type: 'image/png'
                            )
```

I would like to restrict user uploads to only png files, however this doesn't works and it allow all kind off files.

Comment: @Lahiru I correct it thanks, but it's not the source of the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content_type, as used in your example, is an argument whose value is used to tell S3 what the content-type of the uploaded object *actually is* -- that is, what you have determined it to be -- not to restrict what's allowed.

Depending on the application, and how important this restriction is, you will either need to validate the upload's genuine content type either on the client, or on the server, after upload.

There is no simple solution.  S3 trusts that you, generating the signed post upload, knew the content-type of the object being uploaded and set it accordingly, so it accepts the value you sent.

Comment: oh I see! I am doing direct upload from the browser, so I think the way to go is when the visitor add a file -> ajax request containing the file type to create the signed post and get it back (but I think even by sending the file extension via ajax, it's not sure that the file is really a png or jpg or whatever)

Comment: the other way to go is uploading to the server and then save to s3, but will that affect much the performance ? I don't want the upload to block other request from being processed

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether to what extent this might help you, as I did not test this.

But as per this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/PresignedPost.html), I guess you would be able to overcome this by using something like this:

```
bucket.presigned_post.where(:content_type).starts_with("image/png")
```

Refer this answer on [s3 direct upload restricting file size and type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type) too.

Please note that I wanted to point this out if by any chance you missed this and hope it might be of some help.

Comment: That would prevent setting the `Content-Type` *header* to anything else.  It wouldn't actually prevent a malicious user from uploading whatever actual kind of content with forged header.   Good point, though.

Comment: Understood @Michael-sqlbot :) In my case I only restricted by using `carrierwave` gem. So wasn't sure about this direct upload method.