# S3 Pre-signed POST validate file type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know it's possible to put a limit on the file size with the `content-length-range` header. But is it possible to validate the file type?

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HTTPPOSTForms.html#PolicyConditions

I see there is a `Content-Type` header, if I set this to say, `audio/mp3` would that only allow MP3 files and return an error if the file is not an mp3?

I found this previous question but the answers only mention validating the file size: [s3 direct upload restricting file size and type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13390343/s3-direct-upload-restricting-file-size-and-type)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the Content-Type at your POST request.

You can also specify it at your signature, so the post must be done with that Content-Type:

```
{ "expiration": "2007-12-01T12:00:00.000Z",
  "conditions": [
    {"acl": "public-read" },
    {"bucket": "johnsmith" },
    {"Content-Type: "audio/mp3"}
  ]
}
```

[Creating an HTML Form (Using AWS Signature Version 4)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTForms.html)

edit: At the previous question that you found, they are actually checking the Content-Type.

Comment: I specified the `Content-Type` on the policy, but I think that just means it will add that header to whatever file is uploaded. I just tried uploading a png image and it is still uploaded, with the `Content-Type: audio/mp3` header added in metadata.

Comment: The Content-Type on the policy must be the same as the Content-Type sended within the POST request, so you can set the Content-Type in your backend (or wherever you are making the signatures) instead of sending the Content-Type from the frontend. You can also check the Content-Type in your backend when signing and fail if the Content-Type is not what you want.

Comment: So I would need to change the Content-Type header when the user chooses a file to be uploaded before posting the form?

Comment: Just set the Content-Type according to the file content type and check-it in your backend before returning the signature to upload the file.

Comment: Hmm, so then I'd need two AJAX requests. One to check the file type on change and another to upload directly to S3?

Comment: An AJAX request with every onChange event could be a lot of AJAX calls without sense. I would do two AJAX calls, both on form submit. One to sign/check the policy, and the other directly to S3 to upload the content.

Comment: Yeah. It just seems like this should be able to be done with S3 :/

Comment: And it would also require JS to be enabled.