# AWS S3 : limit file size and billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've looked [others answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25269243/8035683) about this question but didn't find what I am looking for.

I am uploading file to S3 from the browser using an ajax POST request. The signature is generated and send to the client from the server. I limit file upload size to 3MB using `['content-length-range', 0, 3000000]` and it works.

Here is my issue. If I upload a bigger file, let's say 25MB, the file is first entirely uploaded, then S3 send back an error because the file is too large. But the error is only sent after it was fully uploaded and rejected, so It seems I used AWS bandwith.

If the file is then rejected by AWS, will I be billed for the bandwith used during my POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All data transfer into S3 is free.

See the [S3 pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

As jarmod replied, you won't be charged for put requests (income data transfer).

Also, if you can manage restrictions on client side to prevent large uploads, it is good enough.

Comment: I can prevent on client side, but as we can never trust client side, I was afraid a hacker could bypass that client side restriction to upload a large file I will have to pay. But as I won't be charged for income data transfer, it's all good.

Comment: @DamienMonni Don't forget that on S3 you pay 3 concepts: Request, Storage and DataTransfer (be careful with each one) [more info](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/)