# Checking if file size is bigger than post_max_size

Tags: php

i'm trying to check if file size is bigger than post_max_size with this kind.

```
class uploadPic
{
private $_imageInfo = array();


public function __construct($file = array()){

    if(empty($file)){
        echo 'File is bigger than post_max_size limit.'; //post_max_size
        return false;
    }
    echo 'Files are ok';


}
```

Is this kind right?
I wonder, if there is a nice method for checking file size?

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: Well, exceeding the `post_max_size_limit` is *one* of the potential reasons for the file not appearing in the `$_FILES`, but not the only one.

Comment: @Sammitch but how will i check it properly?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Not with PHP anyway. Put a note next to your upload box that says "Max Size: *X* MB", and see @kirsty-mclaughlin's answer for a Javascript suggestion.

Comment: @Sammitch thank you, so i will write my class like filesize is ok and checking them after upload with php, before instantiate object, first i will check file size via javascript. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to make a deduction about a file's size from the serverside. Ideally, you want to do this on the clientside, so the user isn't pointlessly uploading a file, or wasting time for PHP to tell not upload it anyway.

Think of a Javascript / Clientside based solution. How to do this is answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966076/getting-file-size-in-javascript) question, if you decide to use Javascript as your client side language.

Comment: Thank you for answer, if user's browser doesnt support js?