# Can i find the number of pages and size of a tiff file before uploading it?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, silverlight

in my application Tiff, PDF and other image files are uploaded. I want to validate if selected tiff file size is less then 10mb and number of pages in it is less then 20 then upload it. Or simply show a prompt.

Is this possible in any way? Please feel free to suggest third party plugins or silver light or any thing.

Thanx

Comment: Its not possible to get additional info of any file unless and until you upload it to server and then check it. Its like how can i know if mango is sweet or not without eating it.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Itextsharp](https://www.google.com.ua/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=2o-MU5TnF87BNOK7gogG#q=itextsharp) is the good idea for parse and create operations for PDF files.
For Tiff size use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281640/how-do-i-get-a-human-readable-file-size-in-bytes-abbreviation-using-net)

Comment: i want it before uploading. it take lots of to upload and then return size and number of pages for tiff.

Comment: And filesize depends on your js-way to organize the download process. May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/2966102/2957717

Comment: yes its perfect for PDF, but i need same type of thing for tiff.

Comment: I'm afraid, that every file should have its own approach of page-count, unless you can convert it to the one universal file(for example doc-> pdf, ect) and just then get required information. I am not sure, that this is good solution (especially for big files), so you'd better make some predefined size checks and perform deep validation on server.