# How to know file size in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to know uploaded files size using javascript? I am uploading multiple files and I want to know each file size ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting file size in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966076/getting-file-size-in-javascript)

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717793/javascript-file-upload-size-validation

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give it a try

```
$('#image').bind('change', function () {
  var size = (this.files[0].size / 1024 / 1024) + " MB";
  alert('Size of the file: ' + size);
});
```

Comment: What is $? How do you know the OP has an element with ID image?