# Get Filesize on cordova (ionic) of downloaded file

Tags: javascript, android, file, ionic-framework

I'm working on an ionic app for Android and iOS. Within the app I load some video files to the local file system. So far everything works fine. Now I want to validate the loaded file by size. I have the info about the filesize within my app.
But I can't find a way to get the size of the local loaded file. FileReader doesn't has such properties.
Any hints?
thx,
patrik

Comment: Maybe this can satisfy your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966076/getting-file-size-in-javascript

Comment: No, they all asume that you have access to the file file on dom (File[0]..) but that don't apply for my prob.