# getting file information without uploading using scala

Tags: scala, file

Can we get file information such as filesize, path of a file(even a large one) without actually uploading it onto the server using scala? PS. I know it can be done using Javascript, but I am searching for another way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getting file size in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966076/getting-file-size-in-javascript)

Comment: Can you help us by explaining how you will identify the file that you are interested in? Do you have a URL, or some other identifier?

Comment: You definitely need to specify in what context you expect the code to be executed and where the file is located. If it is in the browser, it has to be JavaScript although you can use Scala.JS to cross-compile Scala into JS.