# Is it possible to get file size statically from file-loader?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-file-loader

I have a static file that is dynamically fetched by the page via the URL I get from file-loader. The loading can take some time, so I want to show a progress bar, but the server doesn't return a `Content-Length` so the progress event has total set to 0. I can hardcode the file size, but it would be much better if file-loader exported the actual file size along with its public URL.

Currently:

```
import FilePath from './LargeFile.dat';
const FileSize = 12345678;

// handle progress event from XMLHttpRequest/axios
function onProgress(e) {
  reportProgress(e.loaded / (e.total || FileSize));
}
```

Would like:

```
import FileInfo from './LargeFile.dat';
const { path: FilePath, size: FileSize } = FileInfo;

// handle progress event from XMLHttpRequest/axios
function onProgress(e) {
  reportProgress(e.loaded / (e.total || FileSize));
}
```

Is it possible to do with `file-loader` or a similar plugin?

Comment: I believe this thread will answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966076/getting-file-size-in-javascript

Comment: That thread has no mention of webpack at all o_o