# Check size file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I want to define the size for the Index file. Like if    index.size >200 kb make crash in code. How to make that with js file in the same project?

```
var angle = cr.to_clamped_radians(a);
    var lower = cr.to_clamped_radians(la);
    var upper = cr.to_clamped_radians(ua);
    var obtuse = (!cr.angleClockwise(upper, lower));
    
  //var indexfile = "/index.html";
  //size = indexfile.size ;
  //indexfile.size = 7819 ;
    
  //if (indexname.size > 99999999)  // && indexname.size
  // {

  // return;
  // }



     var indexfile = "/index.html"; 

        if (indexfile.size > 200kb) 
        {
            
            return;
        }

    
    if (obtuse)
        return !(!cr.angleClockwise(angle, lower) && cr.angleClockwise(angle, upper)  && indexfile.size );
    else
        return cr.angleClockwise(angle, lower) && !cr.angleClockwise(angle, upper);
};
```

Comment: you don't give us any context? are you running this in nodejs? and how are you even loading the file like that?

Comment: Is this a node.js question? Vanilla javascript will run into major issues with this approach.

Comment: In the same project ; i dont use node.js

Comment: JavaScript running on a webpage doesn't have access to the filesystem, for security reasons.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting file size in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2966076/getting-file-size-in-javascript)