# Uploading large file just returns blank page in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, httprequest

Suddenly, my ASP.NET web application is returning completely blank HTML pages after you upload overly large files. (Like a 6MB file - I've set the various request lengths and file upload settings to limit it to 5MB).

The page is really blank, View Source in chrome reveals nothing, completely empty. In IE, it's a "This page can’t be displayed" error.

Stepping through the code, it's clear that the codebehind of the upload buttons (which executes when the file is small) is never executed. The blank page comes up instantly as soon as the file is uploaded.

I put a pretty standard **Application_Error()** method in **Global.asax** and it catches the error you'd expect (HttpUnhandledException.ErrorCode = -2147467259) and it can Server.Transfer() the user to my own custom error aspx page, I can even hit a breakpoint in the page load of that and step through it, but once it's done... I just get the blank page.

Anyone have any ideas? Something I could try?

Comment: Have you looked at the eventlog on the server?  Generally you will some "ugly" red triangles near some .Net Application events.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET terminates processing the request if its length exceed allowed limit set in `maxrequestlength`.

If you want to catch the exception, try to get it as explained at

[How to catch ConfigurationErrorsException for violating maxRequestLength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756448/how-to-catch-configurationerrorsexception-for-violating-maxrequestlength/2756710)

Another way is to set maxrequestlength higher than the required limit and check file size in the code

```
protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (fileUpload.HasFile && fileUpload.FileContent.Length > 5*1024)
    {
        // too big
    } 
}
```