# Fileupload large file size error handling

Tags: c#, asp.net

My web.config setting is as below:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="5000" executionTimeout="120"/>
```

My error handling code in Global.asax:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
    //Exception ex;

    string sourcepath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);
    if (string.Compare(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Path), "vendorMassUpload.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    {
        System.Exception lastException = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpException httpException = (HttpException)lastException;
        int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        int errorCode = httpException.ErrorCode;
        if (errorCode == -2147467259)
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("~/vendorManagement/vendorMassUpload.aspx?fileTooLarge=true");
        }
    }
}
```

The file size I use to upload in testing is 4999 KB.
It will reach the `Response.Redirect` but it just show me `This page can’t be displayed` in Internet Explorer.

If I `throw new Exception("testing exception");` in `ButtonUpload_Click` with `if (errorCode == -2147467259)` commented, everything just work.

What went wrong?

All I want to do is redirect user and show them custom message when they upload large file instead of telling them `This page can’t be displayed`.

Comment: By default, ASP .NET terminates processing request without throwing exception if the input file size is greater than `maxrequestlength`. This solution may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2756448/how-to-catch-configurationerrorsexception-for-violating-maxrequestlength/2756710

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto thanks to your link, I found out that my code didn't work in Visual Studio development web server but it work in local IIS. But still why?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when uploaded file size exceeds `maxRequestLength` limit in `web.config` file will returning HttpException, thus you can try redirect handling based on exception's message:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sourcepath = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Path);
    if (string.Compare(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Path), "vendorMassUpload.aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0)
    {
        System.Exception lastException = Server.GetLastError();
        HttpException httpException = (HttpException)lastException;
        int httpCode = httpException.GetHttpCode();
        int errorCode = httpException.ErrorCode;

        // check if returned exception contains "exceed"
        if (lastException != null && lastException is HttpException && lastException.Message.Contains("exceed"))
        {
            Server.ClearError();
            // redirect to custom error page
            Response.Redirect("~/vendorManagement/vendorMassUpload.aspx?fileTooLarge=true");
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this may helpful, CMIIW.